# Override spring bean without an alias that is also the parent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, overriding

I have a bean in *module1-spring.xml*-

```
<bean id="parent" class="com.Parent"/>

<bean id="service" class="com.Service">
    <property name="parent" ref="parent"/>
</bean>
```

I want to override the bean in *module2-spring.xml*-

```
<bean id="child" class="com.Child" parent="parent"/>
```

I want `child` to be passed in service instead of `parent`.
If I alias `child` as `parent` i.e.

```
<alias id="child" alias="parent"/>
```

then the parent attribute will read child instead of parent bean and fail on server startup with error-

> BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name
>   'child' defined in class path resource [module2-spring.xml]: Could not
>   resolve parent bean definition 'parent'.

What is the correct way of overriding parent while its also the parent of child?

Comment: Any reason why this can't be done: <property name="parent"  ref="child"/>

Comment: @Daud : exactly what I am doing now....overriding 'service' instead of 'parent'....But I believe there must be a more elegant solution....after all the purpose was to override 'parent' not 'service'....!!

Comment: That would make it a recursive loop. There might be ways of bypassing it using xml ordering, but IMO, it would be a poor design. Plus, what you want isn't overriding, but aliasing, and that's usually not encouraged as it leads to less comprehensible code. One way to think about is, is to imagine there were no XML files and you were injecting all dependencies in Java. Would this setup make sense in that case? Maybe that would give more ideas as to alternative ways of doing this

Comment: @Daud : That happened precisely when I tried overriding 'service'.

Comment: Your `child` bean extends `parent` but the `child` is the `parent` due to the alias. Hence a circular reference and thus it won't work.

Comment: @Daud : That happened precisely when I tried overriding 'service'. That does makes sense. For now, I have simply copied the entire definition of 'service' from 'module1' to 'module2' and injected 'child'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the *service* bean in *module2* and injecting *child* fixed the issue.
***module2-spring.xml-***

```
<bean id="service" class="com.Service">
    <property name="parent" ref="child"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<bean id="child" class="com.Child" parent="parent"/>`
With `<bean id="child" class="com.Child" />`